# How to get cropped thumbnail source for custom post type

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails, images

I need thumbnail image url with size 148*148px. I using custom post type for testimonials. I need just the image source like http://example.com/demoimage.jpg. It is possible to get cropped image source. 'add_image_size' doesn't solve my problem. I have some classes and some data attribute in my <img> tag. Please help
Thank You

Comment: Does your custom post type support thumbnails? If you use `add_image_size` to define the size of the thumbnail you need, every time you upload a new image it will be cropped/resized to the specified dimensions. You may need to regenerate the thumbnails for images previously uploaded. [Force regenerated thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/) is a good choice to do it.

Comment: hi cybnet
Thanks for the information. It worked for me when I regenerated the thumbnails.

Comment: So, the answer you have marked is not the correct answer. You should unmark it to not confuse other people.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your custom image size with this code:

```
add_image_size( 'my-test-image-size', 148, 148, true );
```

Then in your template file you can get cropped image using [wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) like this:

```
$attachment_id = ...;  // i.e. get_post_thumbnail_id()
$image_info = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'my-test-image-size');
echo '<img src="'. $image_info[0] .'" ... />';  // $image_info[0] contains url of cropped image
```

To be more precise... `wp_get_attachment_image_src` returns an array containing:

- [0] => url
- [1] => width
- [2] => height
- [3] => boolean: true if $url is a resized image, false if it is the original.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src
Thanks for your answer krzysiek... I have already seen the article, and I am not able to deploy it, as it doesn't crop the image but adds height and width thats why I posted the question. Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: It worked when i regenerated the thumbnails. thanks